# AIX - how to change user shell to bash?

Tags: unix, aix

I want to know how I can run `bash` automatically when I log into my AIX server. How can I do that without having to type `bash` every time I log into my AIX server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You normally would run `chsh` (see for example *[Changing Shells on IBM AIX](http://www.unix.com/aix/16676-changing-shells-ibm-aix.html)*).  However, if `bash` is not listed in these files, then you could break your login:

- /etc/shells **and**
- /etc/security/login.defs

As a workaround, you could make your shell's login initialization script run `bash` directly.  That would work if your shell is `csh`, for instance, by modifying `.login`.

If your login shell is `ksh`, that is a little harder: AIX's ksh uses `.profile` (which is used by other shells), and does not set special variables.  Something like this might work for you, in `.profile`:

```
[ $SHLVL = 1 ] && exec bash
```

Both ksh and bash set this variable; it should be `1` as you just log in, and incremented when you transfer to bash.

When experimenting with things like this, it is **important** to have a workable shell *on* the remote machine, and test logins using a different connection, in case there is a problem with your edits.

Comment: i have this: `Current available shells:
                /bin/sh
                /bin/bsh
                /bin/csh
                /bin/ksh
                /bin/tsh
                /bin/ksh93
                /usr/bin/sh
                /usr/bin/bsh
                /usr/bin/csh
                /usr/bin/ksh
                /usr/bin/tsh
                /usr/bin/ksh93
                /usr/sbin/uucp/uucico
                /usr/sbin/sliplogin
                /usr/sbin/snappd
                /usr/bin/rksh
                /usr/bin/rksh93
 ejab7330's current login shell:
                /usr/bin/ksh`

Answer (score 1):

Thomas reminded me of this. I use several AIX servers and not all servers have bash. I do prefer bash though. I put this in my .profile.

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    # Interactive session. Try switching to bash.
    if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then # do nothing if running under bash already
      bash=$(command -v bash)
      if [ -x "$bash" ]; then
        export SHELL="$bash"
        exec "$bash"
      fi
    fi
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise is using 'smitty user' utility under root permission.

Go to "Change characteristics of a user"

Type the username and verify the value on "Initial Program" field.

On this, you can change as you consider (/usr/bin/xxxx).

Edu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).